# Listview duplicate action?

Tags: android, listview-adapter

I have list. a row is content image and text and icon, The icon use to make the row is important. when i click on icon the color of icon is change. All is work probably but when i click on one icon more than one of icon is affect.

I see more post here put not fix the problem, I use view holder class also not fix, can Any body help me

this class to save elements

```
public class ItemsList{
    private String imgUrl , comName ;
    private int isStr ;

    public ItemsList(){

    }

    public ItemsList(String imgUrl,String comName,int isStr) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        this.comName = comName;
        this.isStr = isStr;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public String getComName() {
        return comName;
    }

    public void setComName(String comName) {
        this.comName = comName;
    }

    public int getIsStr() {
        return isStr;
    }

    public void setIsStr(int isStr) {
        this.isStr = isStr;
    }

}
```

this is my view holder class

```
public class ViewHolder {
    public NetworkImageView imgInv;
    public TextView comName;
    public ImageView isStr;

}
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ItemsList> itemsList;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();

    public ListAdapter(Activity activity, List<ItemsList> itemsList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.itemsList= itemsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(inflater == null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        final ViewHolder viHold ;
        final ItemsList it;
        if(view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tst_list_row,null);
            viHold = new ViewHolder();
            viHold.comName = view.findViewById(R.id.com_name);
            viHold.imgInv = view.findViewById(R.id.tst_img);
            viHold.isStr = view.findViewById(R.id.img_str);

            view.setTag(viHold);
        }else{
            viHold = (ViewHolderInv) view.getTag();
        }
        if(imageLoader == null){
            imageLoader = AppControllerProf.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
        }

        it = itemsList.get(position);
        viHold.comName.setText(it.getComName());
        viHold.imgInv.setImageUrl(Constant.URL_INV_IMG+it.getImgUrl(),imageLoader);

        // is Stars
        if (it.getIsStr() == 1) {
            viHold.isStr.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
        } else {
            viHold.isStr.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border);
        }

        viHold.isStr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (it.getIsStr() == 1) {
                    viHold.isStr.setImageDrawable(null);
                    viHold.isStr.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border);
                    it.setIsStr(0);
                } else {
                    viHold.isStr.setImageDrawable(null);
                    viHold.isStr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
                    it.setIsStr(1);
                }
            }
        });

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        return view;

    }


}
```

I use Volley library to fill a list
My Activity

```
public class InboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
// Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<ItemsList> itemsList= new ArrayList<ItemsList>();
    private ListView listView;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);

        inboxOnCreate();
    }

    private void inboxOnCreate() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inv_list_inbox);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, itemsList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        final int idShare = SharedPrefManager.getUserID();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("id", String.valueOf(idShare));

        CustomRequest invReq = new CustomRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                Constant.URL_INBOX,
                params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int count = 0; count < response.length(); count++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(count);

                                ItemsList Items = new ItemsList();

                                Items.setImgUrl(obj.getString("com_img"));
                                Items.setComName(obj.getString("com_name"));
                                Items.setIsStr(obj.getInt("isStr"));

                                itemsList.add(Items);

                            }// end try
                            catch(JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }// end catch
                        }//end for loop

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        AppControllerProf.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(invReq);

    }// end inboxOnCreate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's everything ok in your adapter. Problem maybe in your activity class where you are using this adapter can you show code of your activity where you are using this adapter?

**update**
Did you try `view.findViewById(R.id.img_str).setImageResource(...` instead of `viHold.isStr.setImageResource(...`?

Comment: I Update my post and send activity

Comment: Updated answer also

Comment: Your question is not clear. but if you mean use like this 
            view.findViewById(R.id.img_str).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_star); Also I try use this way , also i try used with out view holder also not fix and not found what is mistake